# How to get a Class Object from the Class Name in Java

Tags: java, reflection, class

I know the class name, say **"MyClass"** and want to retrieve the `Class` object, ie. **MyClass.class** for future references. Is there a way to do that?

I've looked through the web but most of the things I found related to it were about the `ClassLoader`, which I presume are not suitable for my case. I do not want to initialize a class, but only get a class object for future uses.

EDIT: Regarding the first answers to this:

I've already checked the `forName()` method but I thought that is supposed to also initialize the class. Now I can call it with the full arguments and pass `false` to the second argument, but would the third have to be `null` or what?

Would

```
Class.forName("MyClass", false, null);
```

return `MyClass.class`?

In fact, what I want to do, is replace an array of String IDs associated with `Class` objects, with an array of IDs from which the class objects are fetched automatically, to get rid of some manual work :)

Thanks for the quick answers and sorry for not mentioning this before.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use:

```
Class c = Class.forName("com.package.MyClass");
```

And later instantiate an object:

```
Object obj = c.newInstance();
```

EDIT: This is just the simplest use case.  As indicated in the comments, you will need to consider constructor arguments and exceptions thrown by the initialization process.  The [JavaDocs for `newInstance`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) has all the details.

Comment: Class.newInstance does evil stuff with exceptions.

Comment: Yes.  You will need to handle any initialization exceptions.

Comment: For this to work, the class must have an accessible no-args constructor.

Answer (score 8):

```
Class.forName("MyClass")
```

Read [the JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) for details

Comment: If you don't want to initialise the class, you need the three-argument form.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you might be able to use the [`Class` class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)'s static [`forName` method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 3):

It's also worth noting that the above suggestions are correct, but will only work for default (parameterless) constructors.  You could also do something like:

```
    public Object newInstance(String className, Object...args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        if(args == null || args.length == 0) {
            return clazz.newInstance();
        }

        List<Class<?>> argTypes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        for(Object object : args) {
            argTypes.add(object.getClass());
        }
        Constructor<?> explicitConstructor = clazz.getConstructor(argTypes.toArray(new Class[argTypes.size()]));
        return explicitConstructor.newInstance(args);
    }
```

Comment: This won't work if one of the arguments is a subclass or implementation of a type that the constructor wants.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to specify the full package name, call:

```
Class.forName("MyClass", true, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

This syntax allows you to reorganize the project, or copy this code into another project, as long as you move **MyClass** along with it.  Thanks to [Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) for reminding me to read the docs!

Comment: hello, i try this ,it don't work, it occur ClassNotFoundException